# Is it bad for SEO to 301 redirect the homepage URL to a deeper URL?

Tags: seo, url, 301-redirect, homepage

For some reason we need to 301 redirect homepage URL to another URL for a while. Eg:

- we would use a 301 redirect from `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/a-catgory/b-catgory`
- we would add a canonical `<link rel="canonical" href="www.example.com">` in
  `www.example.com/a-catgory/b-catgory`

Because we have a technical issue, we can't make `www.example.com/a-catgory/b-catgory` served from `www.example.com` immediately.
Is bad for the SEO of the homepage URL `www.example.com`?

Comment: Your canonical URLs shouldn't redirect.   If you are going to redirect to a deep page, that deep page becomes the canonical.

Comment: Can you explain more about the technical issue?  It is usually possible (even easy) to use `mod_rewrite` to show content from a deep URL directly at the home URL without any redirects.

Comment: Our old homepage is confusion (CFM), and new homepage is PHP.
We will change to new server, and engineer said if we want to use `www.example.com`, need some time to operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an incorrect implementation.

1. You are using a `301 redirect` which indicates permanent redirect.
2. You are using a canonical tag to indicate that the main URL is the one being permanently redirected.

So, if you want to maintain the actual redirects and keep your home as the canonical URL, you need to use a `302 redirect` instead of `301 redirect`.

That would indicate to searchers that the redirect is temporary and the main URL must remain the home.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
We will use `302 redirect` instead of `301 redirect`.
Thanks for your detailed explanation again!

Answer (score 2):

Canonical tags aren't needed when doing a redirect. I agree with Emirodgar to use a temporary redirect. As for the SEO part, you can use Yoast and set the home title and description. If not, you can also create a page that pulls out the category and you can set the title and description from there.

Comment: I agree that canonical tags aren't appropriate.   However your advice about Yoast is specific to WordPress sites.   I don't see any indication in the question that they are using WordPress.